# ftp connection and upload what happens to connection if there is exception

Tags: vb.net

Below  is code for how you can upload a file using ftp. My question is what happens if there is an exception in the try, will the ftp connection automatically close in the catch? Is it better to use a "using"?

thank you

```
Try
  'connect to ftp server
  Dim ftp As New FTPConnection
  ftp.ServerAddress = "ftp.example.com"
  ftp.UserName = "example_user"
  ftp.Password = "example_pass"
  ftp.Connect()
  ftp.TransferType = FTPTransferType.BINARY

  'upload a file
  ftp.UploadFile("s:\test.txt", "test.txt")

  'close the connection
  ftp.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't close if an exception occurs before `ftp.Close()` has finished executing. You should use a `Finally` block to make sure that `ftp` is always closed, even if an exception occurs. This means you should define `ftp` at a higher scope level than within the try block, so that it is accessible within the finally block. You could technically call `Close` from within the catch block but that A) won't cover both/all circumstances and B) might not work anyway if code in the catch throws yet another exception.

```
Dim ftp As New FTPConnection
Try

Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
Finally      
  ftp.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: thanks, --   what happens if it if written in a using statement when there is no close -   when the exception happens will it automatically close??  can you hep me write that?

Comment: A `Using` compiled to a try/catch/finally, so `Dispose` will always be called - you will need to be sure that the `Close` method is called as part of the execution plan for `Dispose` (which is generally the way it is for things that can be 'opened').

Answer (score 1):

When an exception happens (whatever it is) the control flow skips everything until it arrives to a Catch instruction.

So in this case if you have an exception in the UploadFile you will not close the connection.

If the FTPConnection class is IDisposable then your best option is to use the using keyword. Otherwise use the finally statament after the Catch as Grant said.

Comment: Touched on in my comment on my answer: you'd need to be sure `Dispose` called `Close`, which is kind of standard, I know, but a possible oversight if it doesn't.